# Enter drop down values to same column as seperate rows

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, drop-down-menu

I am building a rota.

I have a form with two drop down menus which both submit a name to my database. Currently both values are saved to the one column but I need each name to be displayed individually.

When multiple values exist I can't retrieve just the one name from the column.

Ideally I'd want to be submitting each drop down value in a seperate row with it's own unique row id.

Code to display on profile;

```
<?php foreach($rota_mon as $rota_monday): ?>

<?php if($rota_monday['name'] == 'Gina') {
?>
<img src="images/available.png" width="45" height="45" />
<?php
} else {
?>

<?php } ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Code for drop down form;

```
<form name="" action="rota-insert.php?tbl=rota_sunday" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="rota-edit-fields" id="name" name="name[]">
       <option value="">Choose a Girl</option>
             <?php
                $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, name from persons');
                $stmt->execute();
                   while($name_list = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                echo '<option value=' .$name_list['name']. '>'.$name_list['name'].'</option>';
                   }
                 ?>
    </select> <br />

    <select class="rota-edit-fields" id="name" name="name[]">
       <option value="">Choose a Person</option>
             <?php
                $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, name from persons');
                $stmt->execute();
                   while($name_list = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                echo '<option value=' .$name_list['name']. '>'.$name_list['name'].'</option>';
                   }
                 ?>
    </select> 

        <br /><br />
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="width: 100%;" name="submit" type="submit">Save Changes</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Or any advice on how I can do this better would be appreciated.

Comment: So I struggle to see the problem...is it because you cant tell the difference between the two select fields? Please explain a little more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix my issue by using the following code;

```
<?php foreach($rota_mon as $rota_monday): ?>
                            <?php if(strpos($rota_monday['escort_name'], $_GET['escort']) !== false) { ?>
                                <span style="color:green; font-size:22px;"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <?php } else { ?>
                                <span style="color:red; font-size:22px;"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <?php } ?>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

By matching the value I'm looking for I can cope with values being stored together.